# simple sharing code on facebook error OAuthException 104

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, sharing, facebook-social-plugins

I'm having a php website with sharing code on facebook and Sharethis buttons and script. The head tag contains the fb:app_id, og:title, og:url,og:image but debugging the URL displays the following error

```
  {
   "error": {
   "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
   "type": "OAuthException",
   "code": 104,
   "fbtrace_id": "GO7opPlWLTI"
   }
 }
```

The debug page displays this error

```
fb:app_id hasn't been included in the meta tags. Specify the app ID so that stories shared 
to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url 
when open the share dialog. Otherwise, the default app id( 966242223397117 ) will be assigned
```

When I use the graph to display the page as what facebook gets I don't find the head tag at all. In php it's included in every page and the source code of my page has no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the following page:
https://www.facebook.com/insights

Then use the "Create an App" and "Add your Domain" buttons to generate the app id for your site to be included in the meta tags on your web pages.

```html
<meta property="fb:admins" content="xxxxxxxx" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="yyyyyyyy" />
```

Comment: Now facebook url debugger can't get any information from the webpage hope it's a common problem now it can't detect add id or page title as it was working before

Comment: Facebook could grab the correct data but problem isn't solved after inserting the admin id still getting the same error

Comment: what is the page address